# onCreate on new activity called multiple incremental times every time startActivity is invoked

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on an android app developed in kotlin that has two activities. Being that activity 1 is the main activity and when an specific layout is clicked activity 2, which is a dialog activity is started.

The problem I am having is that each time I click the specific layout on activity 1, the onCreate method on activity 2 is invoked (number of times it was invoked before) + 1 times. Meaning that the first time I click the layout are, the onCreate method is called one time. Then I close activity 2 with finish() and if I click the layout area again, the oncreate method of activity 2 is called two times. If I do that again, 3 times, and then 4, 5, etc.

Activity one goes like the below, where I add the onClick listener to layout area:

```
class ActivityOne : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_one)
        Timber.plant(Timber.debugTree())
        layoutAddNewProject.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(view: View?){
        Timber.d("Click on view ${view.toString()}")
        if (view?.id == layoutAddNewProject.id){
            val intent = Intent(this, ActivityTwo::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Then activity two goes like the below. Note that it has a button which when clicked closes the activity:

```
class ActivityTwo : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
        super.onCreate(savedInstance)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_two)
        setFinishOnTouchOutside(false)
        Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
        Timber.d("Starting activity two")
        btnCancel.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(view: View?){
        if (view?.id == btnCancel.id){
            Timber.d("Cancel pressed")
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

The names of the activities, layout, etc are fictitious, but the code is inline with my real code.

So, the way I figure out onCreate on activity two is being called multiple times, is because I see the log message "Starting activity two" multiple times.

Note also, that when btnCancel is clicked on activity two, I also get the log message "Cancel pressed" multiple times (as many times as the number of times of the onCreate method being invoked).

Your help as always, is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree()) should be called from in Application class onCreate https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber/blob/master/timber-sample/src/main/java/com/example/timber/ExampleApp.java

Comment: @Arpanßløødyßadßøy, did not know that. Thanks! I will fix it next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `Timber#plant` it adds new tree to the list. And then on every `Timber#d` it send message to all trees in that list. So to fix that, you need to call `plant` just once in your application class

Comment: Silly me... Thanks a lot! I added an Application class to the project and this solved the "problem".